# Avoid command dump on terminal when hitting 'Ctrl' twice

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal

Whenever I hit `Ctrl` twice in my terminal, a list of all the possible commands comes up and it takes some time to complete. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: `Ctrl`? I can imagine it with `Tab`, where simple `shopt -s no_empty_cmd_completion` helps.

Comment: What shell does that?

Comment: @choroba your command solves it, if you add it as an answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>? I can imagine it with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, where simple

```
shopt -s no_empty_cmd_completion
```

should help.